# How do I browse my file system on a mac?

Tags: mac

I am trying to browse the file system on a mac yosemite mac book air. I am coming from a Windows and Linux background, so I am used to just firing up an explorer window and being able to navigate everything.

In mac finder, all I get is a favourites window which has a bunch of stuff that is not my hard drives entire file system, and I have a devices tab that has "remote disk" which is empty.

Is there a way I can browse the entire file system through a GUI?

Comment: Nasir's answer will get you into the file hierarchy. If you need/want to dig around in the System itself [with obligatory experienced user warning] then see this Q/A on Ask Different to toggle invisible files on/off - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177132/how-to-set-h-to-enable-show-hidden-files/177138#177138

Comment: Use Cmd-Shift-K to see the drives from the desktop. Use the three column view to move easily through directories.

Comment: You can have a bread crumb trail type of thing by using Cmd+Shift+P. Not ideal but you can navigate up the folder tree with it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Go to Finder > Preferences and under "Show these items on desktop " select "Hard Disks".

Select your drive from the desktop and you can browse the files.

You can also Finder > Go > Computer to browse the files.

Comment: On a similar note, if you go to the Sidebar tab while in Preferences there is a Locations section that will list your device name. Checking it off permanently adds it to the Finder sidebar